# set gradient percentage values by HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to create div containers with a linear gradient background. Their percentage color values are different.

I have a working solution that works when creating these div containers in a loop

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- The percentage values are just variables! -->
<div style="background-image: linear-gradient(blue 0%, red 20%)" class="box">
</div>
```

Is it possible to create a CSS class for the gradient and just set the percentage values by HTML code?

**Pseudo Code**

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.gradient{
  /* no colors provided! */
  background-image: linear-gradient(blue, red) 
}
```

```html
<!-- The percentage values are just variables! -->
<div style="gradientValues: [0%, 20%]" class="box gradient">
</div>
```

I just need to change the values of the gradient, the color is fixed. But I don't want to do it by JavaScript because I create these divs from a ColdFusion code. I don't want to execute JavaScript code when I don't have to. I could refactor the gradient color and put it in a CSS class instead of writing

`style="background-image: linear-gradient(blue VAL1, red VAL2)"`

in my HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes

By using [**CSS Custom Properties**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) (aka CSS Variables)

```css
:root {
  --var1: 0;
  --var2: 50%;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue var(--var1), red var(--var2));
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<div style="--var1:50%; --var2:50%;"></div>
```

Comment: we can also consider the default values of Variable instead of root declaration : https://jsfiddle.net/y0rcz2a8/1/

Comment: So I updated your code and I will use this one :)

https://jsfiddle.net/hLwv6an4/1/